# Is it allowed to set return to json in documentation?

Tags: php, json, string

So, while documenting a php code I'm writing, I stopped where I usually said `@return string The json output`, on functions that I actually returned json.

So, I was wondering if it is right to set

```
*
* @return json
*/
public function test()
{
    $test = array('hola' => array('en' => 'hello', 'ro' => 'salut'));
    return json_encode($test);
}
```

instead of

```
*
* @return string
*/
public function test()
{
    $test = array('hola' => array('en' => 'hello', 'ro' => 'salut'));
    return json_encode($test);
}
```

I searched for related question, and overlooked manuals, but non that I have seen, had mentioned my doubt.

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html

### Update

Just as a reference, of where I got all this started. I saw a couple of times, the following:

```
*
* @return View
*/
```

So, I guess that is a proper return?

Comment: the return value should be a php type... so string it is... but maybe call out that it is json in the comments `@return string JSON encoded return value`

Comment: so, I should stick to `string`

Comment: yeah... you wouldn't put in `@return html` or `@return php_serialized_string` so I wouldn't put `@return json`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"`json`" is not a primitive type in PHP, or in fact any type. You need to document returned *types*, not what the content of these types mean. If you specify `json` as return "type", this implies an object of class `json`, because `json` has no other meaning in PHP.

You can only document it as returning a `string`.

Comment: please, view my updated question, so you understand where my doubt started. And hopefully you will be able to clarify why the other is accepted

Comment: Well, again, anything that's not a PHP primitive is taken as a *class name*. In your example an object of class `View` is returned; and I said if you specified `json` that would mean an object of class `json`.

Answer (score 9):

As orangepill commented, you should use the type `string` and add `JSON` in the description.

`@return string JSON`

[PHPDoc Manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html)

```
@return datatype description
@return datatype1|datatype2 description
```

In reference to the datatype, the manual states

> The datatype should be a valid PHP type (int, string, bool, etc), a
>   **class name** for the type of object returned, or simply "mixed". If you
>   want to explicitly show multiple possible return types, list them
>   pipe-delimited without spaces (e.g. "@return int|string")

Comment: On that note, I always try to comment the return in PHP anyway, where it is not glaringly obvious exactly what would be returned.

Answer (score -2):

I would prefer to see a return type of json.  It's true that you are returning json in the form of a string, however json is more specific, and lets others know what to expect.

Comment: the type in the return is for automated tool, the comments are for humans, json is not a type, it is an encoding.